# Spring JPA Entities: related problems of Ignite error, LAZY fetching, and too-m, minimizing database use and working with Ignite

Tags: spring-data-jpa, ignite, spring-repositories

I'm writing some entity relationships using Spring Data and Java.  I have this pair of classes (edited):

Subject:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SUBJECT")
// Lombok, etc., attributes removed
public class Subject {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "ID", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    @JsonProperty("id")
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = SubjectResource.class, mappedBy = "subject", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<SubjectResource> resources;
}
```

SubjectResource:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SUBJECT_RESOURCE")
// Lombok, etc., attributes removed
public class SubjectResource {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "ID", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "SUBJECT_ID")
    private Subject subject;
}
```

I'm trying to solve these issues:

**Question 1: Can I manipulate @OneToMany or @ManyToOne to NOT have the child class recurse its parent?**

Fetch of resources returns subject data:

/subject/101:

```
{"id":101,"resources":[{"id":1001,"subject":101},{"id":1002,"subject":101},{"id":1003,"subject":101},{"id":1004,"subject":101}]}
```

/subjectResource/1001:

```
{id:1001,subject:{"id":101,"resources":[{"id":1001,"subject":101},{"id":1002,"subject":101},{"id":1003,"subject":101},{"id":1004,"subject":101}]}}
```

That is, /subjectResource/1001 returns its ID and the entire /subject/101 query.

How can I have just the subjectResource data, without its parent?

**Question 2: Through @OneToMany or @ManyToOne can I get Hibernate to fetch on a "1" (O(1)) basis?**

When /subjects does its thing, it works with Hibernate on a "n+1" (O(n)) basis: 1 fetch of subjects, n fetches of resources, one for each subject ID.

I could force a single fetch through a fancy repository @Query annotation ("select s from subject s left join fetch s.resources").  But that means putting the subject : subject_resource definitions in two places, etc.

Can JPA implementation / Hibernate be forced to do a join, and thus make only one database call, through annotation within an entity class?

**Question 3: How do I get my Spring Data / Spring Repository to cooperate with Ignite, and have the cache return the data it already had on the first call?**

I'm usng FetchType.LAZY, as all good pupils do.  I'm also storing things in Apache Ignite.  For /subject/101 the initial call fetches everything OK, returning it in JSON.  But the second call gets from the Ignite cache, which complains about being out of transaction.

How do get my LAZY fetches to cooperate with Ignite?

Thanks,

Jerome.

Comment: Please share Ignite’s full stack trace